# How to determine the smallest interpolation degree required?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, interpolation

Given a set of $n$ points $(x_k, y_k)\ (k\in\{1,...,n\})$, of course a polynomial of degree $n$ can fit all points. However, in some cases the coefficient of the higher degrees actually vanish and one obtains a polynomial of degree $m<n$, e.g. four points that all lie on a parabola. Aside from actually calculating the interpolating polynomial, is there any simpler way to determine the smallest polynomial degree $m\le n$ required to obtain a specific set of points?

Comment: Use progressive interpolation. When the degree is reached, the new points to interpolate will already be interpolated.

Comment: @adamW Good point. It's simpler than the full interpolation, though I was wondering whether something even simpler were possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There cannot really be a way to find the required degree that is significantly simpler than actually calculating the interpolating polynomial. Heuristics: Assume there is such a simple method, then value of the interpolating polynomial at $x$ can be found by determining the single $y$ for which the interpolating poylnomial for the $n$ geiven points polus $(x,y)$ is of degree $<n$.

Comment: Curious. That sounds sensible, though I'll wait a day or so before accepting this answer - you never know...

Answer (score 2):

if the points are uniformly separated (the step between the abscisses is constant) you can use finite differences. if by the end of k diferences you get a constant line, than there exists a polynomial of such degree that interpolates those points. You can then use Newton's trick to find the general term of a sequence passing through those points.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a degree $n-1$ polynomial with unknown coefficients, and write down the set of linear equations that the points give you, and put the linear equations into row echelon form or something.

Comment: ... which is of course equivalent to at least 90% the way to actually calculate the interpolating polynomial